# how do you sort an array of integers but remember their original sort order

Tags: arrays, sorting, logic

How do you sort an array of integers but preserving their original sort order for an undo later  i have very limit memory requirement and no space for any separate cloned copy of original ,index ,fields or transaction scope?

Comment: One option would be to use an array list structure in which each node in the array points to the previous bucket where it used to be.  However, the copy operation might require temporarily doubling the space.

Comment: Beside special cases, sorting is not reversable. So you need a persistent permutation vector that maps indexes in the sorted array to the indexes in the original array.

Comment: there are just 8 integers . 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 i only have 9 buckets 8 for the data and one for the bubble swap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multiply the data by n and add its its original bucket vector. where n is 10 to the power of the length of the highest integer. 1 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Within the constraints that you've specified and given you're sorting something as small as an integer, you don't have many options.

- If you know that the length of your array is going to be less than 2^n for some n < 32 then you can create a smaller array as an index using a smaller number of bits per array element.
- You can compress your original array in-memory, perhaps using a combination of a differential encoding followed by some other low memory overhead compression algorithm, to retain a copy of the original within your memory budget.
- If even that is too much for the memory you can spare, the only other options I can think of is spilling a copy of the original array to disk.